# Как заставить Particle.Systems следовать за касанием

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я пытался так но частицы не появляются на позиций касания

```
void Update () {
            transform.position = new Vector2 (Input.GetTouch (0).position.x, Input.GetTouch (0).position.y);
}
```

этот код находится на частице

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте!
Для того чтобы перетаскивать объект касанием, или мышью, вам нужно перевести из координатной системы экрана на координатную систему игрового мира!

```
void Update () {
    // если убрать эту проверку на количество прикосновений, то может возникать ошибка в Input.touches[0] т.к. оно может быть пустым
    if (Input.touchCount > 0) { 
        if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
            //переводим из экранных координат(пиксели) в координатную систему игрового мира
            Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.touches[0].position);
            // сохраняем дистанцию от экрана дабы объект не стоял на 0 координате оси Z
            pos.z = transform.position.z;
            transform.position = pos;
        }
    }

    // следование за мышью, такая логика как и выше написанный код
    Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    mousePos.z = transform.position.z;
    transform.position = mousePos;

}
```

Возможно код выглядит не очень изящно, но вполне наглядно.

Comment: не знаю кому как он выглядет но если честно то работает! ;)